# Recovering Windows license keys from within a LiveCD environment in Linux

Tags: linux, livecd, license-key

I'm curious if it's possible to retrieve the license keys of a Windows XP machine from within a LiveCD environment in Ubuntu.

Normally, if I was in Windows, I would just run Magical Jellybean Keyfinder, but is there some way to do this from within a LiveCD environment?

Comment: Can MJBKF run under wine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only LiveCD-style way I know of doing this would be using the [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/), which you can boot into from a floppy or CD. Since the key is stored in the registry, this is the logical way to do it. As for the key's location, see [this article](http://teamtutorials.com/windows-tutorials/retrieving-xp-cd-key-from-the-registry).

Comment: Awesome, I think Offline NT Password & Registry Editor is included in UBCD4WIN (which I happen to have on me) so that's great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The Windows Registry files are located at

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\config\
```

1. From your live Linux distro, copy the `%SystemRoot%\System32\config\` folder to a USB drive.
2. On another Windows machine, create a **Windows** directory somewhere and then create a **System32** folder inside that to mimic the directory structure of a real Windows installation.
3. Copy the **config** folder on the USB drive to your new dummy **Windows\System32**.
4. Download and install [Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder v2.0.1](https://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) (MJBKF).
5. Point **MJBKF** to the newly-created **Windows\System32** you created earlier.
6. Let **MJBKF** do its magic.

Comment: I was looking for a solution possible solely from Linux, but I'll keep this in mind as well if I ever need it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sorry not Linux, I meant from a LiveCD.

Comment: No problem. Whatever works for you is the best solution. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hirens boot CD has a Mini Windows XP option with ProduKey built into it, which will let you point to an internal drive.

http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/